# Navbar to Stay Still

Tags: html, css, navbar

I am currently styling out my navbar and have noticed whenever I make the page smaller by scrolling in the words move and the text from the navbar now heads into my paragraph.

How can I make this fixed so minimising the page won't lead to my navbar text will stick and not head into my paragraph in the homepage?

```
Navbar code:

nav {
 width: 100%;
 height: 80px;
 font-size: 15px;
}
 


    HTML code 
<nav>
<div class="wrap"></div>
<ul>
    <li><a href="index1.html">Happiness</a></li>
    <li><a href="Index2.html">Example 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="Index3.html">Example 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="Index4.html">Example 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="Index5.html">Example 4</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: If you put a fixed height (`80px`), it's always going to be that height regardless. What do you mean by "so the page won't do anything"?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry I wasn't clear by do nothing I meant so when I minimize the page the text inside the navbar doesn't end up going into my paragraph

Comment: @Samuel could you provide all the relevant code so we can see this behavior you describe?

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. You can put your sample HTML along with your CSS in a snippet demo using the editor .

Comment: To echo previous comments, when posting your code please keep in mind our guidance on creating a [mre] to better help others recreate your issue and more expeditiously resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use display flex in the nav container, then add a minMax to it. This should work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you fzetz I will try this, much appreciated 

Comment: No problem. I hope it worked :)